# awk sum a column and print that sum on each line of input

Tags: bash, sed, awk, printf

My `file.txt` looks like this:

```
1 12
2 18
3 45
4 5
5 71
6 96
7 13
8 12
```

I can sum the second column like this:

`awk '{ sum += $2 } END { print sum }' file.txt`

`272`

What's the neatest way that I can print that sum on each line? This is what I'm expecting:

```
1 12 272
2 18 272
3 45 272
4 5 272
5 71 272
6 96 272
7 13 272
8 12 272
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! Some very useful answers here. Cheers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Kind of standard `awk` way.

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{sum+=$2;next}; {print $0,sum}' file.txt{,}
1 12 272
2 18 272
3 45 272
4 5 272
5 71 272
6 96 272
7 13 272
8 12 272
```

Comment: The `{,}` wildcard suffix is a shorthand for repeating the input file name twice. It's not standard Bourne shell.

Comment: This is canonical AWK and doesn't store the file in memory. It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, Hello, would you please explain based on what reason this awk doesn't store the file in memory? thanks

Comment: @Afshin.Hamedi: The previously accepted answer used an array to store all the lines of the file, then printed them (and the sum) in the `END` clause. It had the advantage of only reading the file once, though. This answer reads each line, but doesn't store them in an array, thus saving memory (especially important if the file is large). It does read the file twice, however.

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
awk -v xyzzy=$(awk '{sum+=$2}END{print sum}' file.txt)
    '{print $0" "xyzzy}' file.txt
```

This unfortunately means going through the information *twice* but, since you have to do it once before you get the total, there's no real way around it. *Any* solution will involve storing up the information before outputting anything (whether in arrays, or going back to the file).

The inner `awk` works out the total and the outer `awk` assigns that to a variable which can be printed along with each line.

Applying that to the file:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
```

gives you, because `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5` is equal to `15`:

```
a 1 15
b 2 15
c 3 15
d 4 15
e 5 15
```

Comment: @codaddict: did you mean " ... _can't_ store ... "?

Answer (score 3):

Use arrays

```
{ 
    a[NR] = $0
    sum += $2
}
END {
    for (x = 1; x <= NR; x++) {
        print a[x], sum
    }
}
```

Output

```
$ awk -f s.awk file.txt 
1 12 272
2 18 272
3 45 272
4 5 272
5 71 272
6 96 272
7 13 272
8 12 272
```

Read more in [Gnu Awk Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arrays)

Answer (score 1):

Offtopic, but in Perl you can do:

```
perl -nale '$s+=$F[1];push(@a,$_);END{print $_." $s" for(@a);}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The ugly solution:

```
awk '{printf "%s ", $0}{system(" awk \047 {sum+=$2}END{print sum} \047  file ")}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

awk, yes, head and paste.

```
$ yes "`<file.txt awk '{ sum += $2 } END { print sum }'`" | head -n `<file.txt wc -l` | paste -d ' ' file.txt -
```